# Clone Windows partition from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, clone, partitioning

So I've got a 120 GB Intel SSD, with a partition for Windows and another for Ubuntu. Ubuntu is my main OS, Windows is for gaming. But now I'm looking to install Mac OS X, and I'd like it to be on the SSD, so I'm looking to move Windows to a different drive (old 160GB external that I took out of it's shell and have been using as a test drive. I keep my games on another external anyways, so performance shouldn't be affected, other than start up time).

What's the best way to go about this? Any good tools for cloning partitions? I ask this because Google is turning up a lot of results on cloning the drive you are actually using/have  Ubuntu installed on, rather than telling me how to clone a totally unrelated partition to another unrelated location.

Oh, and will the new Windows partition let me run it without any prior post-clone tweaking? Any other information regarding this would be much appreciated.

(I'm doing this because I need to get my paws on XCode, and my MacBook Pro is slowly dying).

Comment: Well, all you need is **cfdisk** and **dd**. The only thing that is somewhat questionable is the boot sector. Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7. I do remember installing it being a royal pain, because of some partition related problems.

Comment: Do you have the W7 disc at your disposal?

Comment: Not entirely sure where I've placed it, but I can dig it up if need be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to clone 2 partitions with **dd** - one is where the bootloader/bootmanager resides (needed in order to chainload the OS) [**System Reserved**, usually 100M] and the other one being the actual W7 installation.

Check the partition table with **cfdisk** - it will give you a visual representation. Then delete all partitions on the target drive - **cfdisk** is your friend.

The syntax for cloning can be found on wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29). You will also need a proper **MBR** (it is probably already present on your *test drive*).

You will probably need to assign a **bootable** flag to the [System Reserved] partition as well (that should be the first one cloned) - **cfdisk** can accomplish that.

If that fails - simply boot from a W7 installation disc and follow the guidelines [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-mbr-xp-vista/) for Vista.

**UPDATE**:

Forgot to mention one important part of the whole process that might not be so evident. You will either have to clone the partition table off the original drive and delete everything but the 2 Windows-related partitions OR recreate them with **cfdisk** / **parted** with the **same** size.

Here's a few examples (assuming, that **sda** is your source drive and **sdb** is the target):

> **dd if=/dev/sda bs=1 skip=446 count=66 of=/dev/sdb seek=446** (this will effectively clone your current DOS partition table along with the MBR signature to the output drive)
>
> **dd if=/dev/sda bs=1 skip=440 count=72 of=/dev/sdb seek=440** (this will also copy the disk ID which can sometimes result in a failed boot if missing - however, such disks will not be able to work together on a Windows environment, until the ID is changed)
>
> **parted /dev/sda u s p** (this is how you can inspect the current partition table and size in sectors on the source drive for later replication on the target with either **cfdisk** or **parted** itself)

Comment: That is a pain and doesn't usually boot up

Comment: Why? If there is a problem with the boot process - instantiating a command prompt session from the W7 install disc and executing **bootrec /fixmbr**, **bootrec /fixboot** or **bootrec /rebuildbcd** should be able to fix the issue.

Comment: fair enough. I had it fail for me in the past. i'm sure that's why I found out about utils to prevent the mishap. Also, using dd to replicate the partition is at least not very efficient

Comment: because it uses a sector-by-sector copy and would copy over empty space in the allocated filesystem? I think, in the OPs context, this is probably going to be completely irrelevant. We don't even know whether the partition is full or not, not to mention him caring for a waiting a few extra minutes (the gain in time might be minimal) instead of trying a less clear alternative solution

Comment: but it has the distinct advantage of being able to copy to a partition of different size. DD assumes the destination is exactly the same size (albeit, it may be _bigger_). This could be a hampering problem, especially when SSDs are involved (they are not of _'unlimited'_ capacity)

Comment: I'm, somewhat, not really sure that I'm following this.. The OP is copying from a 120G drive to a 160G drive. He will be copying to a partition of the _same_ size. The destination _is_ going to be exactly the same size. Overall, the target drive is bigger, but the partition dimensions are going to be absolutely the same. By my understanding, he should not encounter any problems, as he is merely copying an address space of binary data from 1 device to another with the _same_ boundaries.

Comment: Ok, I'm used to the SO spirit where generic answers are preferred. You are right for the OP, I agree

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at

- ntfsclone (copies only sectors in use)
- [fixntfs.c](http://www.grhack.gr/codes/source/fixntfs.c) to fix up the boot info offsets

IIRC, [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/) contains the necessary software as well as many others (ssh, partimage, fdisk, fdisk, cfdisk, parted, gparted, testdisk, ntfsfix; ntfs-3g mounting, rsync etc. etc.)
.

```
/*
 * fixntfs: change some attributes of an NTFS bootsector
 *
 * brought to you by Phoenix
 * url: www.grhack.gr/phoenix
 * mail: phoenix@grhack.gr
 * irc: phoenix -> #grhack -> undernet
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fd;
    FILE *idfd;
    struct stat fst;
    unsigned char cab[32];
    unsigned short log_heads;
    unsigned short ntfs_heads;
    unsigned short force_heads;
    unsigned short ntfs_cab;
    unsigned long long sectors;
    unsigned long long new_sectors;

    log_heads = 0;
    ntfs_heads = 0;
    force_heads = 0;
    ntfs_cab = 0;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\n\t%s <device> <total_sectors> <force_heads>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Stating file %s... ", argv[1]);

    stat(argv[1], &fst);

    if(!S_ISBLK(fst.st_mode))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not a block device\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "a block device\n");


    fprintf(stderr, "Opening device %s rw... ", argv[1]);

    fd = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

    if(!fd)
    {
        perror("open device");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "ok\n");


    fprintf(stderr, "Checking partition... ");

    fseek(fd, 3, SEEK_SET);

    if(fread(cab, 1, 4, fd) != 4)
    {
        perror("read system_id");
        exit(-1);
    }

    cab[5] = 0;

    if(strncmp(cab, "NTFS", 4))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", cab);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", cab);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector heads... ");

    fseek(fd, 0x1a, SEEK_SET);

    ntfs_heads = 0;

    fread(&ntfs_heads, 1, 2, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", ntfs_heads);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector sectors... ");

    fseek(fd, 0x18, SEEK_SET);

    ntfs_cab = 0;

    fread(&ntfs_cab, 1, 2, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", ntfs_cab);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector sectors_per_cluster... ");

    fseek(fd, 0x0d, SEEK_SET);

    ntfs_cab = 0;

    fread(&ntfs_cab, 1, 1, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", ntfs_cab);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector sectors_size... ");

    fseek(fd, 0x0b, SEEK_SET);

    ntfs_cab = 0;

    fread(&ntfs_cab, 1, 2, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", ntfs_cab);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector boot_loader_routine_jump... ");

    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    bzero(cab, sizeof(cab));

    fread(cab, 1, 3, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", cab[0], cab[1], cab[2]);

    fprintf(stderr, "Reading NTFS bootsector total_sectors... ");

    fseek(fd, 0x28, SEEK_SET);

    sectors = 0;

    fread(&sectors, 1, 8, fd);

    fprintf(stderr, "%Lu\n", sectors);


    fprintf(stderr, "Reading device logical heads... ");

    sprintf(cab, "/proc/ide/hd%c/geometry", *(strrchr(argv[1],'/') + 3));

    idfd = fopen(cab, "r");

    if(!idfd)
    {
        perror(cab);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fscanf(idfd, "%*s %*s\n");

    fscanf(idfd, "%*s %s\n", cab);

    *(strrchr(cab, '/')) = 0;

    log_heads = (unsigned short) atoi(strchr(cab, '/') + 1);

    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", log_heads);

    if(argc == 4)
    {
        force_heads=atoi(argv[3]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Forcing heads to %u\n", force_heads);
        log_heads=force_heads;
    }

    if(fclose(fd) == EOF)
    {
        perror("close device");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(log_heads != ntfs_heads)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Heads are different... Logical=%u NTFS=%u\n\n"
                "Update NTFS bootsector? (y/n) ",
                log_heads, ntfs_heads);

        if(getc(stdin) == 'y')
        {
            fd = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

            if(!fd)
            {
                perror("open device");
                exit(-1);
            }

            ntfs_heads = log_heads;

            fseek(fd, 0x1a, SEEK_SET);

            fwrite(&ntfs_heads, 1, 2, fd);


            fprintf(stderr, "\nBootsector updated... Verifying... ");

            fclose(fd);

            fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

            if(!fd)
            {
                perror("open device");
                exit(-1);
            }

            fseek(fd, 0x1a, SEEK_SET);

            ntfs_heads = 0;

            fread(&ntfs_heads, 1, 2, fd);

            if(ntfs_heads == log_heads)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "ok\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "error [%u]\n", ntfs_heads);
                exit(-1);
            }
            fclose(fd);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nHeads update cancelled...\n");
        }

        getc(stdin);
    }

    if(argc >= 3 && atoll(argv[2]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Update NTFS bootsector total_sectors from %Lu to %Lu? (y/n) ",
                sectors, atoll(argv[2]));

        if(getc(stdin) == 'y')
        {
            fd = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

            if(!fd)
            {
                perror("open device");
                exit(-1);
            }

            new_sectors = atoll(argv[2]);

            fseek(fd, 0x28, SEEK_SET);

            fwrite(&new_sectors, 1, 8, fd);


            fprintf(stderr, "\nBootsector updated... Verifying... ");

            fclose(fd);

            fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

            if(!fd)
            {
                perror("open device");
                exit(-1);
            }

            fseek(fd, 0x28, SEEK_SET);

            sectors = 0;

            fread(&sectors, 1, 8, fd);

            if(sectors == new_sectors)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "ok\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "error [%Lu]\n", sectors);
                exit(-1);
            }

            fclose(fd);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nTotal_sectors update cancelled...\n");
        }
        getc(stdin);
    }

    return(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [how-to for cloning a Windows drive](http://www.nilbus.com/linux/disk-copy.php) worked splendidly for me. Since this is the first time I've been able to transfer a Windows install to a new hard drive, I'll share my procedure here to help the next Googler to visit.

*My situation:*
Manager's Windows 7 x64 had maxed out its 128G SSD, so I bought a 240 GB replacement.

*Problem:*
I have two [SATA drive docks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00180MMZC) but linux didn't recognize both at the same time, preventing an easy copy between them.

*Hardware:*
I am about to set up a dual NIC firewall, so I installed the source SSD in this computer. Destination 240G SSD went into external dock.

*Process:*
1) The first USB stick I pick up had Linux Mint live CD on it, which became `/dev/sda1`
2) "Old" 128G SSD was detected and became `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`
3) Used <kbd># fdisk -l /dev/sdb</kbd> from the tutorial and copied the source partition window's information to Gedit.
*-- Note, the tutorial includes the `-u` option, however for me, fdisk was already displaying blocks (the desired output) so including that switch gives the wrong information.*
4) Plug in and turn on the drive dock with destination 240G SSD, which becomes `/dev/sdc`.
5) Use <kbd>fdisk /dev/sdc</kbd> to create partitions on `/dev/sdc` that exactly match `/dev/sdb`, including boot and system flags.
6) <kbd>dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1</kbd> to copy the MBR to destination drive.
*-- The guide now suggests using `hdparm` to turn on DMA, but the command failed for me*
7) <kbd>ntfsclone -O /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1</kbd> to copy the windows hidden system partition.
*-- `-O` or `--overwrite` option is used to set the destination, making the command appear backwards. Kudos to Linux Mint live CD having ntfsclone, as I hadn't heard of this command before & I didn't have to get on the network.*
8) Use <kbd>ntfsclone -O /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdb2</kbd> to copy the windows "C Drive". This took a few beers to complete.
9) For resizing the partition, I used <kbd>gparted</kbd>
10) Reinstalled new SSD in windows computer and it runs checkdisk (I had left the tutorial & didn't notice he does this).
11) Rebooted Windows and all is back to normal but with more free space.